# Error in getting sender's certificate for Outlook VSTO solution

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

While working on Outlook VSTO solution, facing an issue for getting email sender's certificate (PR_USER_X509_CERTIFICATE) when PR_ADDRTYPE_W is  SMTP whereas in case of EX i.e. EXCHANGE no exception thrown for below code.

Here is my sample code of C# to get user certificate

```
NameSpace mapiNamespace = mailItem.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
Recipient emailSender = mapiNamespace.CreateRecipient(mailItem.SenderEmailAddress);
emailSender.Resolve(); 
 
object[] senderCertificateInfo = emailSender.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3A701102");
```

I have analyzed the difference of both types of emails via OutlookSpy. As per my findings,  for EXCHANGE lot of additional properties are also available with PR_USER_X509_CERTIFICATE but for SMTP, a very few properties available as compare of EXCHANGE emails.

Can someone assist me to get sender certificate for all cases?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unless the certificate was somehow sent along with the message, there is no place for Outlook to pull a certificate from in case of an one-off SMTP address.

In case of "EX" type senders, the certificate is stored in GAL, where you can read it from. There is no central world-wide repository of SMTP addresses. The best you can do is check if you have a local contact with a matching SMTP address that might have a certificate stored, but you are the one who would need to add that certificate to that contact to begin with.